# UITableViewCell contentView custom disclosure image frame issue

Tags: ios, uitableview

Disclaimer: I've been working too late.  But, I'm determined to get through this one tonight.

I have an app where I support different color themes.  The dark cell backgrounds have been problematic.

I've been poking around trying to find a formidable way to draw the accessory disclosure icon in uitableviewcells with black backgrounds.

I decided to try overriding setAccessoryType to inherit the functionality for my 50+ views:

```
-(void) addWhiteDisclosureImage {
    UIImageView *disclosureView = (UIImageView*) [self.contentView viewWithTag:kDisclosureReplacementImageTag];

    if(!disclosureView) {
        [super setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        disclosureView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.whiteDisclosureImage];
        disclosureView.tag = kDisclosureReplacementImageTag;
        disclosureView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

DebugLog(@"%f, %f", self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

        [self.contentView addSubview:disclosureView];
        [self.contentView bringSubviewToFront:disclosureView];
        [disclosureView release];
    }
}

- (void)setAccessoryType:(UITableViewCellAccessoryType)accessoryType {
    if(accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator) {
        if ([self.viewController isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerBase class]]) {
            ViewControllerBase *view = (ViewControllerBase*) self.viewController;
            if(view.colorTheme && view.colorTheme.controlBackgroundColor) {
                if([ViewColors colorAverage:view.colorTheme.controlBackgroundColor] < 0.2) { //substitute white disclosure indicator
                    [self addWhiteDisclosureImage];
                    return;
                } else { //not dark enough
                    [self removeWhiteDisclosureImage];
                    [super setAccessoryType:accessoryType];
                    return;
                }

            } else { //no colorTheme.backgroundColor
                [self removeWhiteDisclosureImage];
                [super setAccessoryType:accessoryType];
                return;
            }
        } else { //viewController is not type ViewControllerBase
            [self removeWhiteDisclosureImage];
            [super setAccessoryType:accessoryType];
            return;
        }

    }

    UIView *disclosureView = [self.contentView viewWithTag:kDisclosureReplacementImageTag];
    if(disclosureView)
        [disclosureView removeFromSuperview];
    [super setAccessoryType:accessoryType];
}
```

This override is typically called in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

It seemed like a good option until I drill down and come back.  For some cells, the cell frame will be a great deal larger than the first time through.  This consistently happens to the same cell in a list of 6 that I've been testing against.  There's clearly something unique about this cell: it's frame.size.

Here is the size of the cell that I log for the first tableview load (in some cases every load/reload):
320.000000, 44.000000

This is the difference in what I get for some (not all) of the cells after call to reloadData:
759.000000, 44.000000

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Update: the suspect cell's custom accessory disclosure view almost acts like it's autoresizing flag is set to none.  I confirmed this by setting all to none.  I say almost because I see it line up where it should be after reloadData.  A split second later it moves clear over to the left (where they all end up when I opt for no autoresizing).

Comment: Answer is: don't mess around with subviews and calculating frames, just replace the accessoryView with the new imageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mess around with subviews and calculating frames.
Just replace the accessoryView with the new imageView.  Let iOS do the work.